# is there a way to register JSON schemas into the confluent schema registry using curl commands successfully?

Tags: apache-kafka, jsonschema, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to register a new schema into confluent schema registry using the command below:

```
echo '{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "age": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "profession": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Status": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "education": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}' | \
jq '. | {schema: tojson}' | \
curl   -X POST "https://schema-registry.dev/subjects/cld-dev-pub-json-test-value/versions" -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -d @- 
{
  "error_code": 42201,
  "message": "Either the input schema or one its references is invalid"
}
```

And it keeps on failing but when I use the kafka-json-schema-console-producer it seems to work:

```
kafka-json-schema-console-producer --bootstrap-server kafka00.dev:9095 --producer.config kafka-client-dev.properties --topic cld-dev-pub-json-test --property schema.registry.url=https://schema-registry.dev --property basic.auth.credentials.source=USER_INFO --property schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info=username:password --property value.schema='{"type":"object","properties":{"id":{"type":"integer"} , "age":{"type":"integer"} , "profession":{"type":"string"},"Status" : {"type": "string" }, "education" : {"type": "string" }}}' < json_data.txt
```

and when I check the schema  in schema-registry seems to be fine:

```
curl  -s  -u <USERNAME:PASSWORD>  https://schema-registry.dev.kafka/subjects/cld-dev-pub-json-test-value/versions/latest | jq 
{
  "subject": "cld-dev-pub-json-test-value",
  "version": 8,
  "id": 2639,
  "schemaType": "JSON",
  "schema": "{\"type\":\"object\",\"properties\":{\"id\":{\"type\":\"integer\"},\"age\":{\"type\":\"integer\"},\"profession\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"Status\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"education\":{\"type\":\"string\"}}}"
}
```

So it looks like the kafka-json-schema-console-producer api is using a different parser to do the schema validation. Also I am trying to follow the examples from Robin Moffat:

https://rmoff.net/2019/01/17/confluent-schema-registry-rest-api-cheatsheet/

and even though I raised this issue with confluent support the engineers could not provide me with the solution.

Any ideas how can I overcome this?

thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Linked blog is several years old, and uses Avro, not JSON.

The [registry API has changed](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#post--subjects-(string-%20subject)-versions) to now have two optional fields of `schemaType` and `references`.

The default schemaType will be AVRO, for backwards compatibility, not JSON.

Try this

```bash
echo '{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "age": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "profession": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Status": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "education": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}' | \
jq '. | {schema: tojson, schemaType: "JSON"}'
```

e.g.

```json
{
  "schema": "{\"type\":\"object\",\"properties\":{\"id\":{\"type\":\"integer\"},\"age\":{\"type\":\"integer\"},\"profession\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"Status\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"education\":{\"type\":\"string\"}}}",
  "schemaType": "JSON"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @OneCricketeer's answer.

```bash
echo '{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "age": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "profession": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Status": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "education": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}' | \
jq '. | {schema: tojson, schemaType: "JSON"}' | \
curl -X POST "https://schema-registry.dev/subjects/cld-dev-pub-json-test-value/versions" -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -d @-
```

This should be the whole command to register the schema.

Comment: You could've just commented the curl command on my answer

Comment: I have tried it but it was unreadable.